# Getting error in creating trigger function using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a trigger function to delete records automatically , if time limit of that data exceeds.

Here is the code-

```
CREATE FUNCTION delete_old_rows() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  row_count int;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM tablename1 WHERE timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day';
  IF found THEN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS row_count = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'DELETEd % row(s) FROM tablename1', row_count;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

I am getting following error-
ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 5: AS $BODY$CREATE FUNCTION delete_old_rows() RETURNS trigger.

Comment: That's [perfectly valid](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3361ada4c934611224f8629056995278) - which tool are you using to run that? And what is your exact Postgres version (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: 11.5 version ...

Comment: You should use a different client that does not split the SQL string at dollar-quoted semicolons.

Comment: I am using PGadmin4 , can you please explain?

Comment: You might have some invisible character causing this. Copy and paste it in a text editor like notepad++, set it to show all characters, and see if there's anything dodgy there. This can happen especially if you've copy/pasted any part of it from some web page or document with formatted characters.

Answer (score 0):

While the trigger function itself looks you might want to table a good look at

Return NULL ;

As you did not post the actual trigger. From the [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger
>   manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e.,
>   subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does
>   not occur for this row). If a nonnull value is returned then the
>   operation proceeds with that row value. Returning a row value
>   different from the original value of NEW alters the row that will be
>   inserted or updated. Thus, if the trigger function wants the
>   triggering action to succeed normally without altering the row value,
>   NEW (or a value equal thereto) has to be returned. To alter the row to
>   be stored, it is possible to replace single values directly in NEW and
>   return the modified NEW, or to build a complete new record/row to
>   return. In the case of a before-trigger on DELETE, the returned value
>   has no direct effect, but it has to be nonnull to allow the trigger
>   action to proceed. Note that NEW is null in DELETE triggers, so
>   returning that is usually not sensible. The usual idiom in DELETE
>   triggers is to return OLD.

Comment: "The usual idiom in DELETE triggers is to return OLD". So pretty basic change "Return Null"  to "Return Old"

Comment: My comment/answer addressed **only** the return null statement - nothing else. Look at the other comments. Especially the comment by 404.